# Pyspark 2 values from different dataframes into 1 df?

Tags: python, pyspark

Suppose I have two dfs:

df:A

```
A
-
1
```

df:B

```
B
-
2
```

And both these DFs will **never have more 1 row**, I want a resulting third df which is basically `A/B` like:

```
C
-
0.5
```

In SQL this can be doing by doing `SELECT dfa.A/dfb.B from dfa A INNER JOIN dfb B ON TRUE`

But how can this be doing in PySpark in a clean and efficient way?

Comment: If you want the solution in `Pyspark`, why have you tagged `pandas`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal sorry, I must have pressed the suggested tags

Comment: @MayankPorwal on second thought, the solution might be similar actually for both

Comment: Syntaxes for both kinda differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same SQL logic in PySpark

```py
df_a = spark.createDataFrame([(1, ), ], ("A", ))
df_b = spark.createDataFrame([(2, ), ], ("B", ))

df_a.join(df_b).selectExpr("(A / B) as C").show()
```

### output

```
+---+
|  C|
+---+
|0.5|
+---+
```